# XSS: Escape the escape - How to deal with trailing single quote without comments in JavaScript context?

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

Given an application which prints user-supplied values inside single quotes in a JavaScript context while escaping `'` - but not `\` -, is there a way to gain XSS without `/`?

Example code:

```
<script>
    test('input1, fixed, input2', '/some/path?somearguments');
</script>
```

Transformations for user input:

```
' -> \'
\ -> \ (not transformed)
not allowed: <, >, /
```

It's possible to exit the string context by escaping the escape via `input1=\',alert(1),`, but the trailing `'` is preventing execution and can't be commented out via `//`.

Injecting a second quote via `input2` also doesn't work trivially, as `\\'`/`\'` in a non-string context is invalid.

Is there still a way to gain XSS (eg via some JavaScript quirk which can be used to handle the trailing `'`), or is this - while not using proper XSS protection - secure?

Comment: The path behind is completely static?

Comment: @Arminius `somearguments` is partly user-supplied (same values as `input1`/`input2`), but all characters are properly URL-encoded here. `/some/path?` is static. It's a tough one :(

Comment: From your excerpt I don't see an obvious way either. What I'm thinking is maybe some tricks with template literals (which span multiple lines, so maybe they open up another injection point), using slashes from the path for regexes (a single quote in a regex expression doesn't cause a syntax error), using a slash from the path to construct a mutliline comment, ... But no straightfoward idea here. :(

Comment: @Arminius Thanks, those are all good ideas (though none work^^). The script is short and template literals can't have `</script>` in them, so there's no other injection point by using them; input1: `\'` and input2: `=` is interesting as it moves the error up to the `?`, but that's it; `*` or an additional `/` sadly can't be inserted into `/some/path`. But thanks anyway! I'll let you know if I figure something out.